# Flow doesn't allow me to pass generics with more properties to child that expects less properties

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a generic type that I'm using on several places.

Sometimes I have to compose components that take slightly different versions of the same generic (basically the same generic but with less props). I expect to be able to pass objects with more props to component that expect them have less props, but flow is not allowing me to do it.

So, for a very simple generic like this:

```
export type Form<T: {} = {}> = {
  data: T,
}>
```

I should be able to pass it down like this:

```
type MyData = $ReadOnly<{ cool: boolean, superCool: boolean }>

type MyOtherData = $ReadOnly<{ cool: boolean }>

type OProps = {
  form: Form<MyOtherData>,
}

const OPstuff = function(p:OProps){

  return <div>Soy yo</div>
}

type PProps = {
  form: Form<MyData>,
  stuff: string[]
}

const PPstuff = function(p:PProps){

  return <OPstuff form={p.form}></OPstuff>
}
```

But flow is complaining that the parent one has more props, which should not be a problem.

At first I thought that it may be a mutation problem, that makes sense after all, but after annotating everything as read-only I'm getting the same error:

```
export type Form<T: $ReadOnly<{}> = {}> = $ReadOnly<{
  data: $ReadOnly<T>,
}>
```

Error:

```
28:   return <OPstuff form={p.form}>Soy puto</OPstuff>
                            ^ Cannot create `OPstuff` element because property `superCool` is missing in object type [1] but exists in object type [2] in type argument `T` [3] of property `form`. [prop-missing]
References:
13:   form: Form<MyOtherData>,
                 ^ [1]
22:   form: Form<MyData>,
                 ^ [2]
4: export type Form<T: $ReadOnly<{}> = {}> = $ReadOnly<{
```

[Here is a flow repl](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOGATzCTgDFoQAeAFQC44ASZCgAmAeQB2AG3ocA3gF8AfHAC8cBcrWDUYqTNmk4cYShgo+2kROndFAGlJLyDJnACy9ACKmUqgUN0bWTg0CAhJPgAjMMlUcTs4AGcAVyYoAGEYqJi4uCdSF2YPURgACyQobzM-S0D9EKy4aPDc-MK4UQAFHDBEvwMjTHY+NihOYrKKqpR7R3JQ8UT4LqXkzEw-TGTxDGAIcQAKMB4unsSASgNDOCIYZKhxOA5hYAA3RQBlCHo4eggOAD0L3ecwKjGYnW6EF6-WuQzGI3YHA801mRlW6z4SygwHEAHMANoAXVBCyWcEhGI2ai2Oxge0Ox0hZ0u5CMt3ujw4Kzu6zg8JAKlkYAAdAKlICeWtMIpQUA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this to flow maintainers and seems that I was actually pretty close. I was just missing a [plus sign on the generic type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-variance-sigils). I think I already tried this, but I was obviously wrong. So this is the final generic type:

```
export type Form<+T: $ReadOnly<{}> = {}> = $ReadOnly<{
  data: $ReadOnly<T>,
}>
```

The reason why that many readonlies are needed is because, otherwhise, flow can't guarantee that you will not be adding new fields to a type or even worse, changing the type of the existing ones. By flagging them as RO flow allows you to pass down "compatible" objects because there is a guarantee that the type will not be "corrupted" on the inners of the receiving function.

[Here is the original answer on GH](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8648#issuecomment-827013539)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like flow is doing a direct comparison of object properties to see if they're compatible, so indexer might be your friend here

Does this work for your use case?

```
type MyOtherData = $ReadOnly<{ cool: boolean, [key: string]: any }>
```

[try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOGATzCTgDFoQAeAFQC44ASZCgAmAeQB2AG3ocA3gF8AfHAC8cBcrWDUYqTNmk4cYShgo+2kROndFAGlJLyDJnACy9ACKmUqgUN0bWTg0CAhJPgAjMMlUcTs4AGcAVyYoAGEYqJi4uCdSF2YPURgACyQobzM-S0D9EKy4aPC4hIBtAGskej5EmChgcQBzAF0+FHF6PMVnRmZRAAUcMES-AyNMdj42KE5isoqqlHtHclDxPrhFvuTMTD9MZPEMYAhxAAowHkXlxIBKAyGOBEGDJKDiOAcYTAABuigAyhApvQIBwAPTQuGnApzOALJYQFZrIGbXbbdgcDxHE5GG53Xr9QZDNojbHnS74un3NSPZ4wV4fL7434A8hGEFgiEca6gu5wUkgFSyMAAOgVSnRMtumBm8nIQA)

Comment: In this situation no, because that is making the typing weaker and also does not match the actual signature of the other component, which actually needs the extra props